# Using Google Ads APIs with play and scala, how do you correctly add dependencies?

Tags: scala, dependencies, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm trying to add the necessary dependencies for google's ad api to a play app written in scala.
My problem is that all the examples are for java and I can't get it to work for scala.

I've been looking at this setup guide:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/

I took the dependencies for sbt from this site:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-ads

Build.scala:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    //won't work, sbt can't resolve the RELEASE version
    "com.google.api-ads" % "ads-lib" % "RELEASE"
)

val appDependencies = Seq(
    //won't work either, see error below
    "com.google.api-ads" % "ads-lib" % "1.8.0"
)

[warn]  module not found: com.google.api-client#google-api-client;RELEASE              
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/rawphl/Coding/play-2.0.3/framework/../repository/local/com.google.api-     client/google-api-client/RELEASE/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/RELEASE/google-api-client-RELEASE.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/RELEASE/google-api-client-RELEASE.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/RELEASE/google-api-client-RELEASE.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.google.oauth-client#google-oauth-client;RELEASE
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/rawphl/Coding/play-2.0.3/framework/../repository/local/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client/RELEASE/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/RELEASE/google-oauth-client-RELEASE.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/RELEASE/google-oauth-client-RELEASE.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/RELEASE/google-oauth-client-RELEASE.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                       
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.google.api-client#google-api-client;RELEASE: not found
[warn]  :: com.google.oauth-client#google-oauth-client;RELEASE: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I'm not sure how to proceed right now. I guess I'm just missing some dependencies, but I can't quite figure out what the prefered way of adding the google api is.

Comment: Use 1.9.0 and it will be fine.

Comment: Changing the version to 1.9.0 really solved the problem.

Comment: @ron convert your comment to answer so OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 1.9.0 and it will be fine. More generally, check dependencies, check versions, randomize the values and pray.